# Insert not working in list box

Tags: python, if-statement, listbox

so I've been trying to make this work for hours now, my code is supposed to insert a string into this Listbox when the global variable glob is equals to one, I've tried it without the if statement and it does insert the string. Am I missing something here?
Thanks.

```
def open_file(self):
    """
    Function in charge of opening a chosen file with a
    filedialog
    """
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    base = os.path.basename(filename)
    name = base.replace(".csv", "")
    if not base.endswith('.csv'):
        print('Wrong archive')
    else:
        a = AnimalData()
        td=a.load_data(filename)
        global glob
        glob +=1
        tv.append(a.to_tabbed_string(order[name]-1))


class SelectionBox(tk.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, bg='white',relief = tk.RAISED
        if glob == 1:
           self.insert(0, tv[glob-1])
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an example of a minimal complete verfiiable example - IOW, not enough information to answer the question. (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Make sure your code is entering `else` block, add a `print` statement inside `else` clause.